# "Stalled" issue with TTFB

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns

I have a fiber optics on site with static IP address.
On my PC (the server) I have run a VM, and I have forwarded DNS, HTTP/HTTPS and other necessary ports to the VM.

Everything works perfect. But there is an issue.

Note: I am not testing from server network but from other ISP.

The website is https://wps.rs
I always run a fresh incognito session in Google Chrome and open "NETWORK" tab.
I have this "Stalled" that has about 60-80ms.
This only happens on **first incognito session**, but **does not happen with any other website**.

Chrome fresh incognito session:
[image: Stalled]

Safari fresh private session:
[image: Safari fresh private window]

CURL:

```
 curl -o /dev/null -s -w "Connect time: %{time_connect} seconds\nTime to first byte: %{time_starttransfer} seconds\nTotal time: %{time_total} seconds\n" https://wps.rs
```

[image]

How can this be fixed? What should be looked at? Maybe this is a network issue on my ISP  side?

DNS is also hosted at my server. https://intodns.com/wps.rs

I am running NGINX, and page cache is being directly served via NGINX (you can see that in response headers)